# How to modify a String type in a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Say I have a java servlet based web application, and this application reads files on the file system.

Now these files are in constant change, so there is a VERSION variable which is used to reference the correct sub-folder:

```
/app-files/version0001/....
```

If some files are modified, a new version sub-folder is created and the servlet should be looking in here:

```
/app-files/version0002/....
```

How can I create this VERSION variable in my servlet, make it globally accessible and when I need to modify it, I can in a thread-safe manner?

The variable will be modified my an internet service that will make a HTTP request like:

```
www.example.com/updateVersion?v=0003&secretKey=asdf23908234asdjf234
```

Comment: create a public static variable and use synchronized methods to access it

Comment: so you will know the latest version from the request urls ?

Comment: @KaipaMSarma what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you could do it in a number of ways.

1 Create an aplication variable from your selvlet.

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("myversionvariable", "version");//to set it
Object attribute = context.getAttribute("someValue");//to get it
```

2 Create a static string array to put your version number, and create and declare public a get and set method for this variable. As long as the access is public you can change this variable anywhere in your app. Ex. from a JSP

```
<%@ page import="com.servlets.MyServlet" %>   
<% MyServlet.getMyServletVarible(); %>
```

If you need to make it thread safe you could access and change this variable through only one synchronized method Ex.

```
private static String myvarVersion;
private static final int  SET = 1;
public static synchronized String Operation (String value, int operation){
    if(operation == SET){
        myvarVersion = value;
        return "";
    } else{
        return myvarVersion;
    }
}
```

*There are may ways of doing such us using Atomic components, different ways of synchronization, etc.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But will this be accessible from inside of a filter? or only this single servlet?